# Luggage storage at Amsterdam airport?

Tags: luggage, luggage-storage, ams

For my Moscow to Barcelona flight I planned an 8 hr layover in Amsterdam so I can do a quick genealogy errand there.  Is there luggage storage at the Amsterdam airport?

Answer (score 7):

That's easy, see here: https://www.schiphol.nl/en/at-schiphol/services/luggage-storage

Relevant details from that page:

- Locations before security: Baggage basement
- Locations after security: Holland Boulevard, Lounge 1, Lounge 2, Lounge 3